# database value retrieval error showing

Tags: php, mysql, database

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource...
This above error is shown when i am trying to take value from database for 1st featured profile below.....
if i add the :-
        or die(mysql_error());
then it shows no Database selected..
please help
  code:-

```
<div class="grid_1">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Featured Profiles</h1>
        <div class="heart-divider">
            <span class="grey-line"></span>
            <i class="fa fa-heart pink-heart"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-heart grey-heart"></i>
            <span class="grey-line"></span>
        </div>
<?php
    $sql="SELECT (file,user_name,user_id,user_occupation) FROM users1";
    $result_set=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result_set))
    {
        ?>

        <ul id="flexiselDemo3">
          <li><div class="col_1"><a href="view_profile.html">
            <img src="images/<?php echo $row->file ?>" alt="" class="hover-animation image-zoom-in img-responsive"/>
             <div class="layer m_1 hidden-link hover-animation delay1 fade-in">
                <div class="center-middle">About Him</div>
             </div>
             <h3><span class="m_3">Profile ID : <?php echo $row->user_id ?></span><br>28, Christian, Australia<br>Corporate</h3></a></div>
          </li>
          <li><div class="col_1"><a href="view_profile.html">
            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" class="hover-animation image-zoom-in img-responsive"/>
             <div class="layer m_1 hidden-link hover-animation delay1 fade-in">
                <div class="center-middle">About Her</div>
             </div>
             <h3><span class="m_3">Profile ID : MI-387412</span><br>28, Christian, Australia<br>Corporate</h3></a></div>
          </li>
          <li><div class="col_1"><a href="view_profile.html">
            <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" class="hover-animation image-zoom-in img-responsive"/>
             <div class="layer m_1 hidden-link hover-animation delay1 fade-in">
                <div class="center-middle">About Him</div>
             </div>
             <h3><span class="m_3">Profile ID : MI-387412</span><br>28, Christian, Australia<br>Corporate</h3></a></div>
          </li>
          <li><div class="col_1"><a href="view_profile.html">
            <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" class="hover-animation image-zoom-in img-responsive"/>
             <div class="layer m_1 hidden-link hover-animation delay1 fade-in">
                <div class="center-middle">About Her</div>
             </div>
             <h3><span class="m_3">Profile ID : MI-387412</span><br>28, Christian, Australia<br>Corporate</h3></a></div>
          </li>
          <li><div class="col_1"><a href="view_profile.html">
            <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="" class="hover-animation image-zoom-in img-responsive"/>
             <div class="layer m_1 hidden-link hover-animation delay1 fade-in">
                <div class="center-middle">About Him</div>
             </div>
             <h3><span class="m_3">Profile ID : MI-387412</span><br>28, Christian, Australia<br>Corporate</h3></a></div>
          </li>
          <li><div class="col_1"><a href="view_profile.html">
            <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="" class="hover-animation image-zoom-in img-responsive"/>
             <div class="layer m_1 hidden-link hover-animation delay1 fade-in">
                <div class="center-middle">About Her</div>
             </div>
             <h3><span class="m_3">Profile ID : MI-387412</span><br>28, Christian, Australia<br>Corporate</h3></a></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(window).load(function() {
            $("#flexiselDemo3").flexisel({
                visibleItems: 6,
                animationSpeed: 1000,
                autoPlay:false,
                autoPlaySpeed: 3000,            
                pauseOnHover: true,
                enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                responsiveBreakpoints: { 
                    portrait: { 
                        changePoint:480,
                        visibleItems: 1
                    }, 
                    landscape: { 
                        changePoint:640,
                        visibleItems: 2
                    },
                    tablet: { 
                        changePoint:768,
                        visibleItems: 3
                    }
                }
            });

        });
       </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>

        <?php
            }
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap off `( )` from you query!!!Where is your database connection???

Comment: i already did that part above code as:-<?php
include("database/db_conection.php");
?>

Comment: Wrap off bracket form your query it would be `SELECT file,user_name,user_id,user_occupation FROM users1`

Comment: it shows error  (Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given)             i did this :-             <?php
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","users");
 $sql="SELECT file,user_name,user_id,user_occupation FROM users1";                                     
 $result_set=mysql_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result_set))
 {
  ?>

Comment: You are mixing `mysql and mysqli` in your code. Use just mysqli not both at the same thie

Comment: Thnks that Problem Solved....

Comment: One more thing....on querying for image       (<img src="images/ <?php echo $row['file']?>" alt="" class="hover-animation image-zoom-in img-responsive"/>)                       it shows error:-   (Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp\www\abc.com\index.php on line 178 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0014415664{main}( )..\index.php:0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i think the problem lies in your $result function it should have 2 parameters in it and you have given only one so your code should be like

```
<?php
$connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','yourmysqlusername','yourmysqlpassword','yourmysqldatabase');
     $sql="SELECT (file,user_name,user_id,user_occupation) FROM users1";
    //you have to add $connection as 2nd parameter in $result function
        $result_set=mysql_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result_set))
?>
```

Comment: after following ur steps it shows error as:-                                                                Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are first connecting to database using `mysql_select` and then selecting the database using `mysql_select_db`. After this you need to fire query using `mysql_query`.

Also, you can `mysqli_connect` to combine first two steps. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)